# Scalable way to manage aggregated statistics over time in hierarchy?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, hierarchy, tree, django

I'm using a closure table (Postgres through Django) to roll up stats through a hierarchical tree. When a node that is 10 layers deep has a value that increases, each parent's sum total of that value can also be easily calculated at any given time, thanks to the closure table.

Let's say our parent node has 4 children, each of which have 4 children, each of which have 4, etc to the point of 5 layers of depth.

Each node has a `node score` table in which we update their score with new entries that can change a couple times per day, and a calculated column called `family score` that is the sum of its sum of that value for all descendent nodes.

So here's my challenge: In this example, the very top parent has 1363 children whose changing scores influence it's own `family score` calculated value, along with the `family score` of every parent between that one and the one who's `node score` just changed.

I need a way to be able to map any node's `family score` over time. I've come up with two solution, neither of which I think are likely to scale well:

1. Add a `family score` table, and store a new static value for each ancestor node any time a node's score changes. Thus each write is multiplied by the depth of the node whose score is changing. The structure could easily get to 150-300 in depth.
2. When loading the data for the yearly score chart, first get an array of timestamps for each `node score` row within the date range specified and with the given parent specified, and then for each timestamp, find the latest `node score` row for every descendent and sum the values.

Option 1 seems like its less likely to break, but I'm guessing there's a best practice for this type of thing? Searching hasn't produce anything that quite addresses this use case. Any insights would be massively appreciated!!

Comment: Another thought is to have a nightly ETL into a 'data warehouse' of sorts. We'd lose more granular time-based data than daily, but that may be just fine.